# Omitting properties when extending a class

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance

I am trying to derive a class to set a field as optional, with that field being required in the Base class.

e.g.

```typescript
class Base {
  param1! : string;
  param2! : string;
}

class Derived extends Omit<Base, "param1">{
}
```

This results in error ts(2693):

> 'Omit' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

In case this is an XY problem, what I am really trying to solve is:

1. I have generated classes that get regenerated on every build (so I cannot modify them manually, or do something to include the modification when generating)
2. The generated classes define all properties as Required (similar to `Base` above).
3. I need to add decorators to some of the generated methods and properties.
4. I need to allow `Partial` instances of the Base class. (Ideally with the decorators added only once).

Ideally, I would extend the Base class, using `Required`,`Omit`,`Pick`,`Partial` in order to derive multiple classes omitting/requiring the correct properties.

I have almost given up on all this scaffolding/boilerplate stuff and want to manually write out the models/sql/REST by hand.

(I am new to typescript)

Comment: You need to use `implements` instead of `extends`. Because `extends` is used for extending classes, hence TS expect a value whereas you are trying to use `Omit`. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/Na21ym)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, this was the issue. Thank you! So `Pick, Partial, Required, Omit` always 'return' interfaces, regardless of whether a class or interface is given? If you post this as an answer, I will accept, as it covers the main issue in the question. However, while the decorators' effect persists in the derived classes, they are not 'recalculated/reapplied' (i.e. the decorators should have a different effect on an optional type vs required). I s there a way around this? Should I remove this from the question and open a new one? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TS has two scopes (worlds). First is for runtime values, second is for types. According to JS specification and [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends)

> The `extends` keyword can be used to subclass custom classes as well as built-in objects.

It means, that after `extends`, both TypeScript and JavaScript expect runtime value.  This is why you are getting an error, because [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) is a pure type, it is getting erased during compilation.
Using `Omit` in this case is aquivalent to this pure javascript:

```js
class Derived extends {
}
```

This syntax is wrong.
Instead, you need to use `implements`. THis keyword is from type scope and helps TS to validate class declaration.

```js
class Base {
  param1!: string;
  param2!: string;
}

class Derived implements Omit<Base, "param1">{
  param2!: string;
}
```

Regarding, decorators. Please provide a minimum reproducible example with decorators.

Comment: This was precisely the issue. Additionally, in nestjs, there are _`mapped-types` via `PickType`,`PartialType`,`OmitType` et. al specifically for this reason. Under the hood, `function PartialType<T>(classRef: Type<T>): Type<Partial<T>>` to allow inheritance from the Base class (via extends) instead of polymorphism by implementing a modified interface of the Base class. Some of the details are still not clear to me, but this is the correct solution. Thank you!